# Connect to local openfire server android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am developing on Ubuntu. I am trying to connect my xmpp client to local openfire server.

```
AndroidConnectionConfiguration configuration = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(
                host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0); // (I tried after removing this line)
        configuration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true); 
        configuration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(configuration);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "
                    + connection.getHost());
            Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as "
                    + username);
            Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
```

Now I can connect with Google chat server with this code. Also I can connect local server with Spark client on Ubuntu. But fails to connect with local server on Android.

Where **host** as 10.0.2.2 ( Android localhost)
**port** 5222
**service** localhost

Android client can successfully connect with the local server but I can't login

The error I am getting `sasl authentication failed using mechanism digest-md5`

I am searching for past two days and tried so many things but no success with local server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for connection:

```
public static boolean XMPPConnect() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");
            //SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(30000);

            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(Constant._hostName, port);
            //config = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(Constant._hostName);

            //          config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
            //          config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            //          SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(1000*60);
            //          config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
            //          config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
            //          //config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
            config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
            config.setSendPresence(true);
            //SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("MD5");
            config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
            config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
            config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);

            SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(30000);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
                config.setTruststorePassword(null);
                config.setTruststorePath(null);
            }/*else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<19 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {

            }*/ else {
                config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
                String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
                if (path == null)
                    path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                            + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                            + "cacerts.bks";
                config.setTruststorePath(path);
            }

            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            connection.connect();
            debugEnabledReset();




        } catch (Exception e) {
            XMPPConstants.XMPP_ERROR="socket_timeout";
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(connection.DEBUG_ENABLED==true)
                connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = false;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

if its return true then you login to xmpp are as follow:

```
public static boolean XMPPLogin(String uname, String password) {

        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
            public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {}
            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {}
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {}
            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {}
        });

        try {


            //SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("MD5", 0);
            connection.login(uname, password, "Smack");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            XMPPConstants.XMPP_ERROR="Username or password is incorrect";
            if(e.getMessage().toString().contains("No response")){
                XMPPConstants.XMPP_ERROR="Server communication failed";
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(connection.DEBUG_ENABLED==true)
                connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = false;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: remove this line  config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

Comment: Still getting error `Failed to log in as root
SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5: `

Comment: perform changes on ur local openfire server settings like enable SASL authentication on server.

Comment: can you please tell me where I can enable SASL? SSL is enabled on server.

Comment: on ur local server config the openfire where u need to enabled that.